# JMeter - How to set a variable when all Test Plans Threads have passed

Tags: jmeter

I wish to set a global variable indicating that all of my Threads have passed. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a [JSR223 Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Listener) to your Test Plan and use the following code:

```
if (!prev.isSuccessful()) {
    props.put('success', 'false')
}
```

If **any** request fails the code will set `success` property value to `false`, you can check its value using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) as `${__P(success)}` where required.

`prev` stands for current [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) see the JavaDoc for all available functions and [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) guide to learn what else you can do with Groovy scripting in JMeter